# if else if else in angular js

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, slim-lang

I have to incorporate angular in my slim file, I'm not sure how to transform if else block in angular. I know angular don't have ng if else statements but is there a way to change below code to angular

```
- if @cart['empty'] 
   cart is empty
- elsif @cart['invalid']
   can't proceed
- else
  -@cart['Items'].each do |item|
      #{item['description']}
```

I want to achieve some thing like this

```
  ng-if="cart.empty"
     cart is empty

  ng-else-if cart.invalid
     can't proceed

  ng-else
     ng-repeat="cart.Items as item"
          item.description
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is the [ng-switch](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSwitch) directive.

First get some variable that will contain the switch condition:

```
$scope.getStatus = function(cart) {
  if (cart.empty) return 'empty';
  if (cart.invalid) return 'invalid';
}
```

And then use the directive:

```
<div ng-switch = "getStatus(cart)">
  <div ng-switch-when = "empty">Cart is empty</div>
  <div ng-switch-when = "invalid">Can't proceed</div>
  <div ng-switch-default>.... ok ....</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This idea makes sense.  But if rails controller returns error, like @error consists an error message and no cart variable,.  How can I add that condition (if error ) in switch block.

Comment: @tumati assuming you have the error in your scope, give the error to the function `ng-switch = "getStatus(cart, error)"` and getStatus will return 'error' and that's a new ng-switch` statement. Now that you know about `ng-switch` you can developp any approach, we cannot do everything for you